# LLVM- change the default output stream

Tags: llvm

I would like to know how can I change the default output stream for dumping generated IR of a certain module. `module->dump()` uses the console to print the output.I did some search before asking the question here, but as far as I know we are supposed to use a raw_ostream class which I cannot even get an new instance. So please tell me how can I correctly get an instance of  `llvm::raw_ostream`so that I can use it   `llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile` or any other function that dumps LLVM IR (I'd rather dump the IR preferably but dumpint bc is ok also). Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `print` method of `Module` class, you can specify an output stream of your choice.

An output stream can be obtained as follows:

```
std::string errorMessage = ""; 
raw_fd_ostream example_ostream("example_filename", errorMessage, raw_fd_ostream::F_Append);
if(!errorMessage.empty())
  errs() << "Error opening " << example_filename << "\n";
```

`example_ostream` is the handle you need to pass to `print` method. Note that this file is opened in append mode, you might want to change that according to your need.